# Importing Bot Framework Composer skills into PVA: publish to PVA or publish to Azure and import skill?

Tags: botframework

Is better to publish to PVA through Bot Framework Composer or Publish to Azure and then import the skill into PVA? Is there a difference in the architecture\reusability? Can anyone point me at documentation that lists pros\cons? We are at the stage where we know we want to use skills from Bot in PVA, but would like to figure the best way forward for getting those skills into PVA. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on the features that you are using.

PVA is more limited in terms of features - see difference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-virtual-agents/advanced-bot-framework-composer?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003365#composer-features-not-supported-with-power-virtual-agents) . So if you need some of these features, host your skill in Azure. In the other case, it can be done from PVA using the Composer.

Comment: Thanks so much - very helpful article! 
I'm less looking for documentation on Bot Framework Composer VS. PVA but more looking for what is the best way to publish skill bots from Bot Framework Composer to PVA. 
So far I've identified 3 ways to publish skill bots from Bot Composer to PVA:
1) Publish from Bot Framework Composer to Azure Web App and then enter the manifest URL to PVA
2) Publish to PVA directly from Bot Framework Composer
3) Open Bot Composer directly in PVA

Is it all the same or is there a best practice\gotchas to be aware of with these?